# Edit and continue seems to work only intermittently with my console app

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2017, console-application, edit-and-continue

At one point, I used to have no issues editing code while debugging my console apps. Now, editing even simple code like strings and moving IF/THEN blocks around triggers the following message:

[image]

I don't have any plugins installed and don't know what VS settings I could have changed to suddenly cause this to occur. It also appears to be intermittent, meaning I can *sometimes* edit code while debugging. I haven't been able to isolate the specific conditions that trigger the issue.

How can I get it back to the way it was where I could edit almost any code without requiring a restart of the app?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.29
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.29+28307.1300
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03761
```

Comment: Did you try to reset all vs settings by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset all settings`?

Comment: Use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start Vs and then test whether the issue happens or not.

Comment: Could you please share a small sample with us? Or what changes did you make to VS2017 that caused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is an annoying issue and  many people encounter this issue. If the above suggestions do not help you handle the issue, please check this:

I found that many people has encountered this issue. See [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/439396/aspnet-core-mvc-edits-were-made-to-the-code-which.html) and [that one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/705494/without-any-changes-to-source-files-edits-were-mad.html).

**For your issue**, anyway, I have [reported the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1261395/use-edit-and-contunie-option-on-vs2017-debug-and-g.html). And you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

**However**, **VS2017** is the product of the previous generation and maybe you cannot get much tips about it. Also, I found that **Microsoft** investigated this issue under `VS2019 16.3~16.5`.

**Since** the process might take a long time, I suggest you could try to install the latest **VS2019 Community 16.8.1** version and I hope it might have a fix about it. You can try to use that. You do not have to worry about the compatibility when you migrate your project into VS2019 because VS2019 is  compatible with VS2017 for `.NET`.  See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019).

**After all**, as the latest product, **Microsoft** is more motivated to maintain it.

Comment: Installing VS 2019 is actually what I've done (it was time to do so anyway), but I haven't had a chance to see if I encounter the issue there. If it doesn't seem to occur in 2019, it may be best to just abandon this question and advise that upgrading is the best option.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The issue itself is a bit of a mystery, not very easy to reproduce. Also,  since the issue was received by many people and seems to have been raised rarely since 16.5, using the latest version is not a bad idea. Please try VS2019 for  a while, and if there is any problems, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, how about now, did you face the issue on VS2019? If the issue does not persists, I think you could consider accepting the answer. And if it persists, please feel free to let us know. And that is your choice:)